# Javascript map object, skips element and sets a timeout

Tags: javascript

This is my object

```
[0 … 200]
0: {id: 2291798516830927, url: '.....', address: 'new', symbol: '1t43', fav: false}
1: {id: 7337710716729779, url: '.....', address: 'new', symbol: 'gf23525', fav: false}
2: {id: 6962996031953837, url: '.....', address: 'old', symbol: '435234', fav: false}
3: {id: 8456218226475281, url: '.....', address: 'old', symbol: '2345', fav: false}
4: {id: 6759748921116029, url: '.....', address: 'new', symbol: '$B2345ROKE', fav: false}
...


address="new"
bookmarks.map(function (bookmark, index) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if (bookmark.address == address) {
           console.log(bookmark.symbol)
        }
    }, 1000 * index)
})
```

What I want to do is skip all the "old" addresses in my object and continue with the mapping.
There should be a 2 second timeout if possible between each cycle.

if I use Timeout with value "`1000 * index`" after the first two objects I have to wait several minutes before the cycle resumes, it is not clear to me why.

if I use the timeout without with "`1000`" without "`index`" the timeout does not work, the object is printed entirely without timeout

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not clear why". If you set a timeout of 199 seconds (because that's what you do for the 200th element) this timeout will execute after 199 seconds (ie 3 minutes and 20 seconds).

Comment: @derpirscher I explained myself wrong, after 3m and 20secs N elements are printed at the same time without waiting further and so on. The cycle does not run normally again. Anyway the problem is solved, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would filter and not use map. Never use a map when you mean forEach and do not need the array map is creating.

We can use setTimeout or setInterval and clear the inteval when cnt === list.length

```js
const bookmarks = [ {id: 2291798516830927, url: '.....', address: 'new', symbol: '1t43', fav: false},
 {id: 7337710716729779, url: '.....', address: 'new', symbol: 'gf23525', fav: false},
 {id: 6962996031953837, url: '.....', address: 'old', symbol: '435234', fav: false},
 {id: 8456218226475281, url: '.....', address: 'old', symbol: '2345', fav: false},
 {id: 6759748921116029, url: '.....', address: 'new', symbol: '$B2345ROKE', fav: false}
];


const addr="new";
const list = bookmarks.filter(({address}) => address === addr);
let cnt = 0;
const show = () => {
  if (cnt >= list.length) return; // stop the listing
  console.log(list[cnt].symbol);
  cnt++;
  setTimeout(show,2000); // next one
};
show()
```